# How do I reset nautilus to the default configuration?

Tags: 10.10, nautilus, nautilus-elementary

I've reinstalled Nautilus from the maverick repositories after removing nautilus-elementary and the breadcrumb hacks, but I have no longer access to the "preferences" menu and the default toolbar. How do I reset Nautilus to the default configuration?

***Update***: I've tried moving both `~/.nautilus` and `~/.gconf/apps/nautilus` folders as suggested below, but my "Edit" menu is still missing the "Preferences" item. Running the `nautilus-file-management-properties` applet from the command line I'm still seeing the "Tweaks" tab that nautilus-elementary added.

***Solved***: My problems where caused by the wrong `nautilus-data` package being installed. I should have replaced the `nautilus-data` package along with the `nautilus` one when removing nautilus-elementary. Before that I should have known *there was* a `nautilus-data` package ;-)

Answer (score 4):

While nautilus is closed type the following in your terminal,

```
rm -R ~/.gconf/apps/nautilus
```

It will delete the folder with old settings.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess:
Maybe you could try to delete/rename **.nautilus** folder in your profile:

`mv ~/.nautilus ~/.nautilus.bad` (rename) or
`rm -rf ~/.nautilus` (remove)

and then reinstall the nautilus package.

Comment: The ~/.nautilus folder?