# How can I change the defaults in Nautilus in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nautilus, 13.04

It is now called "File" but I guess it is still really Nautilus.
The icons are a big too big for me, taking up too much real estate on the screen. I press zoom out and get a longer list. Likewise I use View as list.

I'm used to the previous Nautilus where it would remember that I switched the directory to display as list. It isn't a big deal, but it would be nice if "File" would remember my choice and next time come up with 1 zoom out and a list display.

Is there an easy way I can set the defaults?
Thanks,
Ilan

Comment: And why not try another file manager like Thunar. The icon size is not a problem, can be changed very easily

Comment: See [this.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/170530/how-do-i-set-nautilus-to-default-view?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

You need Files/Files/Preferences, from the top left hand side of the Panel.
See the image attached;
[image: Nautilus Defaults]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit embarrassed that I didn't find it myself. Hopefully your answer will be useful to others as well. The zoom out is accomplished by using Default zoom level = 50%